# split a number into intervals and feed them into two variables in for loop

Tags: bash

I want to submit a series of jobs to a cluster, I am using a software that runs through each line of a file, but it has an option to define intervals of lines so you can parallelise it.

the command line looks like this:

```
# Run MetaTissueMM (Mixed Model) to obtain estimates of effects
~/Meta-Tissue/Meta-Tissue.v.0.5/./MetaTissueMM \ 
--expr ~/Meta-Tissue/output_gene.txt \
--geno /~Meta-Tissue/output_snp.txt \
--matrix ~/Meta-Tissue/matrix.txt \
--output ~/Meta-Tissue/MetaTissue \
--start_snp_index 0 \
--end_snp_index 1000
```

The variables I want to modify are `--start_snp_index` and `--end_snp_index`, my file has 8743544 lines, so I would like to split them in 1000 intervals, so these two options would be `--start_snp_index 0 --end_snp_index 1000 --start_snp_index 1001 --end_snp_index 2000` and so on.

My knowledge of bash is very limited I try to define range with `{..}` but obviously it doesn't work

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: According to my math teacher, you get to 1 Million lines, when you define 1000 intervals of size 1000 each, or aren't intervals and line index in sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for a in {0..8744}
do
  MetaTissueMM --foo --bar --start_snp_index $((a*1000)) --end_snp_index $(((a+1)*1000))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple counting loop:

```
lines=8743544
for ((start = 0; start <= lines; start += 1000)); do
    prog --start_snp_index $start --end_snp_index $((start + 999))
done
```

In Bash 4, the brace expansion allows to specify increments, so you could use this:

```
for start in {0..8743544..1000}; do
    prog --start_snp_index $start --end_snp_index $((start + 999))
done
```

Note that I'm not a big fan of this brace expansion, because it doesn't allow using variables inside the `{..}` expression.